# Scan SAP Web Dynpro code written in SAP Netweaver Developer Studio using HPE SCA

Tags: java, webdynpro

Can I use HPE Static Code Analyzer to scan SAP Web Dynpro code written in SAP Netweaver Developer Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is no way to do it.